# Expectations - dependence and independence

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$.
Is $E[aX+bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$ true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or even dependent?

And, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is it true that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$? Is this true if they are dependent?

Comment: first one is true regardless of indepdence. second one is true if $X$ and $Y$ are indep, thus not generally true if they are dep.

Comment: First claim is always true. Second claim in some cases is true ( for dependent r.v.), and in some cases is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value?wprov=sfla1) operator is linear. Therefore,
$$E[aX+bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$$
If the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then we have
$$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$$
I hope this helps you understand.